# wp_enqueue_script + wp_enqueue_style Since When

Tags: plugin-development, functions

`wp_enqueue_script` + `wp_enqueue_style`: these 2 are recent inventions in wordpress are they are from many years. I purchase a course from udemy his authors hasn't used these functions. His videos look like a freelance edition. he is saying 1 year back when he made this video it wasn't there.

Please guide me how long since these things have been incorporated into WordPress.

Comment: I do not want to sound discouraging, but you bought yourself a pile of outdated junk. If that videos was made a year after `wp_enqueue_***`, then it is way pre version 3.0. There is such a tremendously huge gap between the version in the video and v4.5. I can promise you, almost everything in that videos is done wrong, or depreciated. PHP and WordPress has come a long way in 8 - 9 years

Comment: Thanks. This was the course that I bought. [link](https://www.udemy.com/bootstrap-to-wordpress/?utm_campaign=email&utm_source=sendgrid.com&utm_medium=email)

Comment: I came to realize because I was learning through Tuts Plus Videos, which are amazingly good and then realized that This Udemy Video is not at all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at either [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) or [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) there's usually a little snippet at the bottom which says:

> **Since:** WordPress x.x.x

If we take a look at [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for example we see toward the bottom above the contributor notes that it has been around:

> **Since:** WordPress 2.1.0

Now we can use the [WordPress Release Chart](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions) to find out when 2.1.0 came out, which it did so **January 22, 2007**. So this function has been around for roughly ~9 years.

Answer (score 1):

wp_enqueue_script is since Wordpress 2.1.0 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

wp_enqueue_style is since Wordpress 2.6.0 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Found via a quick google